# How to alternate values in two columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to create two new columns to alternate starts and endings in a dataframe :

1. for 1 start there is only 1 ending maximum
2. the last start can have no ending corresponding
3. there is no ends before the first start
4. the succession of two or more starts or two or more ends isn't possible

How could I do that without using any loop, so using numpy or pandas functions ?

```
The code to create the dataframe :

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'start':[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
                    'end':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]})
```

```
The render and the result I want :

   start  end  start wanted  end wanted
0       0    1             0           0
1       0    0             0           0
2       1    0             1           0
3       0    0             0           0
4       1    0             0           0
5       0    0             0           0
6       1    0             0           0
7       0    1             0           1
8       0    0             0           0
9       0    1             0           0
10      0    0             0           0
11      1    0             1           0
12      0    0             0           0
13      1    0             0           0
14      0    0             0           0
15      0    1             0           1
16      0    0             0           0
17      1    0             1           0
18      0    0             0           0
```

Comment: why don't you want to use a loop? is your dataframe very large?

Comment: @Dan yes there could be hundreds of thousands of rows

Comment: @Lukx - did you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this with pure pandas/numpy but here's a simple for loop that gives your expected output. I tested it with a pandas dataframe 50,000 times the size of your example data (so around 1 million rows in total) and it runs in roughly 1 second:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'start':[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
                    'end':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]})


start = False
start_wanted = []
end_wanted = []
for s, e in zip(df['start'], df['end']):
    if start:
        if e == 1:
            start = False
        start_wanted.append(0)
        end_wanted.append(e)
    else:
        if s == 1:
            start = True
        start_wanted.append(s)
        end_wanted.append(0)


df['start_wanted'] = start_wanted
df['end_wanted'] = end_wanted

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    end  start  start_wanted  end_wanted
0     1      0             0           0
1     0      0             0           0
2     0      1             1           0
3     0      0             0           0
4     0      1             0           0
5     0      0             0           0
6     0      1             0           0
7     1      0             0           1
8     0      0             0           0
9     1      0             0           0
10    0      0             0           0
11    0      1             1           0
12    0      0             0           0
13    0      1             0           0
14    0      0             0           0
15    1      0             0           1
16    0      0             0           0
17    0      1             1           0
18    0      0             0           0
```

Comment: thanks a lot but are you sure for the speed ? I ran your code and it took 0.005s so *50000 = 250s

Comment: I ran it on: `df = pd.DataFrame({ 'start':[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]*50000,
                    'end':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]*50000})`, takes around 0.9 seconds

Comment: similar results for random data: `df = pd.DataFrame({'start':np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000000),
                   'end': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000000)})`

Comment: I did the test I have the same thing as you, I don't know why I had this result at first. As I'm looking for a pandas answer I won't accept your answer for now in case a better shows up but thanks a lot :)